# How to validate current admin password programmatically magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, password, change-password

I want to validate the admin current password programmatically.
I enter a current password in textbox. Script should check this is valid current password or not.

I used below code

```
$user = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/user');
```

$result = $user->_validateCurrentPassword($user_id,$currentpwd);

Guys, can anybody help me please asap

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After did research and with my buddy's help, I got the solution

```
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($user_id);// user your admin userid
$this->validateHash($currentpwd, $user->getPassword());
```